# MySQL values into associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a table with the rows `id`, `itemid`, `name` and `content`, and I'm writing a function to pull different item's metadata from a table, and need the MySQL values of `name` and `content` to go into an associative array ('name'=>'content'), for mulitupl values. How would I write a loop for that? I was thinking something like:

```
dbCon() 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM metadata WHERE itemid='$id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$meta = array();        

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

 $meta[$row['name']] = $row['content'];

}
```

Comment: So, what's the problem? The example you provide should give you exactly what you want.

Comment: That looks ok, have you actually tried the code? Oh and I hope you're sanitizing the $id variable before inserting it in the query (For example: $id = (int) $id;). Another thing, now you're just grabbing one item on a specific id by using the where condition, omit it and use the limit and order by keywords to build your own dynamic query.

Comment: @kjetilh What do you mean by that last part?

Comment: You said you wanted to pull out different items from the db. Now you're only pulling out 1 item. I also recommended limit and order by because one usually want to limit the amount of items to be shown at once (imagine being a user and having to wait for 1000 items to be loaded) and order by is for ordering the items (maybe you want to order the products alphabetically on name?)

Comment: Yes, but multiple rows will have the same `itemid`, like a photo's EXIF data, or a page's `<meta>` tags. I want to pull every row that has a specific `itemid` and put them all into an associative array for access later in the page.

Comment: Allrighty.. Then you've got it already I believe

Answer (score 0):

Your almost there. Try this:

```
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$meta = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
  $meta[] = $row;
```

All you have to do is build a multi-dimensional array. So each element in the $meta array is the associative array of columns and keys that you are looking for.

You were already really close man. Good job.

Comment: I agree but the code he provided should work too, unless every row has the same 'name'

Comment: That won't give him what he's looking for. The array key(s) will either be numeric (dimention 1) or have key names of `'id', 'itemid', 'name' and 'content'` (dimention 2). He wants the value of `name` to be the array key and the value of `content` to be the value.